# How do I serialize dependencies in JSchema with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

With Newtonsoft.Json.Schema I am trying to add dependencies and serialize to a json-schema (.json file).

```
var schema = new JSchema()
{
    Type = JSchemaType.Object,
    SchemaVersion = new Uri("http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#")
};

schema.Properties.Add("ShowField", new JSchema() { Type = JSchemaType.Boolean });

var oneOf1 = new JSchema();
oneOf1.Properties.Add("ShowField", new JSchema() {Enum = { false }});

var oneOf2 = new JSchema();
oneOf2.Properties.Add("ShowField", new JSchema() { Enum = { true } });
oneOf2.Properties.Add("ExtraField", new JSchema() { Type = JSchemaType.String });

var oneOf = new JSchema();
oneOf.OneOf.Add(oneOf1);
oneOf.OneOf.Add(oneOf2);

schema.Dependencies.Add("ShowField", oneOf);

Console.WriteLine(schema.ToString());
```

My expected and desiered reult is this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "ShowField": {
            "type": "boolean"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "ShowField": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "ShowField": {
                            "enum": [false]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "ShowField": {
                            "enum": [true]
                        },
                        "ExtraField": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the code the result is this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ShowField": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  }
}
```

I have checked the JSchema object, and verified that the dependency is added to the object, but there are still noe serialization of the dependencies.

Any tips? Any errors in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Newtonsof.Json.Schema. It has now been fixed:
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/187